# How the artifact version is determined in my case

Tags: java, maven

In my parent pom, I defined a dependency management entry,and it contains one google guava artifact

```
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

In the `child pom`, there are 3 cases, I would ask which version will child use for each case.

1. There is no version declared, so that it will use the parent's guava version defined in the dependencyManagement? The answer should be yes, and this is the main purpose why dependencyManagement is used for.

```
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

2. The version is declared and lower than the parent's guava version defined in the dependencyManagement, in this case, which version will child use? 32.1.3-jre or 32.1.2-jre?

```
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.2-jre</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

3. The version is declared and upper than the parent's guava version defined in the dependencyManagement, in this case, which version will child use? 32.1.3-jre or 32.1.4-jre?

```
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.4-jre</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can verify this by generating the effective pom.xml for the project. Maven's dependency mediation uses the "nearest definition" of the dependency.

Case 1: Group and artifact ID alone is specified here. So, Maven picks the dependency version from the nearest definition which is in the dependencyManagement section.

Case 2 and 3: Whether the version is higher/lower than versions specified. elsewhere has no meaning for Maven. The group, artifact ID, and version are all specified in the dependency section itself. So this version will be used rather than the one specified in the dependencyManagement section.